# Не подключаются стили normalize.css в gulp

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, gulp, scss

Помогите разобраться в чём проблема, через @import подключаю стили normalize, выдаёт всегда ошибку что файлов нету... Пути менял не один раз, уже даже не знаю какие ещё есть решения.

[image: Подключение стилей в scss]

[image: Ошибка в консоли]

Answer (score 0):

Через обычную тильду "~" решилась проблема)